# Landscape material with ridges and erosion

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I have an modeled  landscape. How to create material with ridges and erosion on it  shown below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would play with the cycles nodes using Pointiness as the factor when mixing bump maps. You could also Sculpt the ridges or paint a texture and use that.

Comment: Could you tel me about Pointiness ? I'm bad with sculpting so I wouldn't do that. What do you mean by mixing bump maps ?

Comment: So you have two bump maps the rough but flat sand and the bumpy rock and the colourisation you need then you use a Mix Shader. At that point the two textures are mashed together. Add a Input/Geometry Node and use the Pointiness output as the Mix Shaders Factor so that only Pointy things get the rock texture. It is not easy to explain and you would do best by playing with it. For instance I added a Math node onto the Pointiness output so I could tweak the amount of terrain considered Pointy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create erosion with the Landscape tool.
Here's a good tutorial for this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3k0rXQTyvg